# $h^2 = x^2 + (x+1)^4$

Tags: geometry, triangles

This is a question I had of finding an exact value of $h$ as I was interested in the process and techniques used. The question was one to do with Pythagoras and the math shown is the question in $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ form.

The question was what is the size of the hypotenuse of a right-angled triangle if one side is a size $x$ and the other is a size $x^2 + 2x + 1$ (which was rewritten as $(x + 1)^2$). I got an answer from Wolfram Alpha of a value for $h$ that does not include $x$, only numbers.

**Wolfram Input:**

[image: Wolfram Alpha Input]

**Wolfram Answer:**
[image: Wolfram Alpha Real Solution]

What would be the process of finding the exact value of `h` as to where there is no sign of `x` in the `h =` equation?

P.S. If the process is simply too lengthy or tedious, feel free to take this question down.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: So did I understand correctly, there is a right triangle with one side of length $x$ and another one of $(x+1)^2$ ? And you should find the hypotenuse? Your title gives the expression for it ... Then what?

Comment: Hint: The hypotenuse if the sides are $a$ and $b$ is $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$. Replace $a$ and $b$ by what they are for your question.

Comment: I feel like this is a rather easy question. You literally just have to plug in the values. But are there any other restrictions? Like integer solutions?

Comment: @MattiP. So sorry it took so long to do but I finally saw your comment and added the input for Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
c^2 &= a^2 + b^2 \\[1em]
h^2 &= x^2 + \left[(x+1)^2\right]^2 \\
h^2 &= x^2 + (x+1)^4 \\
h^2 &= x^2 + x^4 + 4x^3 + 6x^2 + 4x +1\\
h^2 &= x^4 + 4x^3 + 7x^2 + 4x +1\\
h   &= \sqrt{x^4 + 4x^3 + 7x^2 + 4x +1}
\end{align}

You probably put into Wolfram Alpha some other task - you wanted the **square root**, and you obtained the **root** (= solution) of the system of equations with unknowns $h$ and $x$.

**Addendum:**

If you wanted from Wolfram Alpha the result of my computing, enter into it

```
solve(h^2 = x^2 + (x+1)^4, h)
```

(`h` at the end determines which you want to compute), and you will obtain

$$h   = \pm \sqrt{x^4 + 4x^3 + 7x^2 + 4x +1}$$

If you want the result for a particular $x$, enter its value, e. g.

```
h^2 = x^2 + (x+1)^4, x=1
```

to obtain plot

[image]

and solutions
$$\begin{array}{l}{h=-\sqrt{17}, \quad x=1} \\ {h=\sqrt{17}, \quad x=1}\end{array}$$

Comment: So is this the only way of answering it? Is the Wolfram Alpha way wrong for my type of question?

Comment: @ChristianAlbina, I have no information about your input into Wolfram Alpha - I think that you wrote into it something *other* that you want to receive. Simply not appropriate formulating your problem. Why not edit your question and reveal your input into Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: I added an image of the input.

Comment: As I supposed, your image shows, that you entered in Wolfram Alpha the equation in 2 unknows - and Wolfram Alpha did the best for compute them. I will extend my answer to show you the appropriate input.

Comment: I see now. I was hoping that Wolfram Alpha used some sort of technique for figuring out 2 unknowns when no values are given which I was really interested in learning but the idea that one can have a value only when another is given (say solving what h is when you're given x) is much more reasonable. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're welcome.